# setProgressDrawble is filling whole progress bar

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I have an progress bar -

```
  <ProgressBar
                android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_anim"
                android:minHeight="10dip"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:maxHeight="10dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:progress="0"
                android:max="100"
                android:id="@+id/scoreProgress"/>
```

and i want to set it's progress color programmatically . I am doing this

```
scoreProgress.setProgress(unikTopics.getScore());
scoreProgress.getProgressDrawable().getCurrent()
.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(progressColor[counter])
android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

and this is progress_anim.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#808080"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

The problem is that if I am not setting progressdrawble color programmatically , i am getting fine result with progress being shown in red color and rest part in greyish color but if i set it programmatically whole progress bar is getting flled with that color ?

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've got the problem of the progressbar being filled with progressDrawable just using XML! I've been stuck on this problem for 2 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are coloring the entire drawable (all layers).  You need to grab the `@android:id/progress` layer from the drawable and color it specifically.

Try this:

```
scoreProgress.setProgress(unikTopics.getScore());
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable)scoreProgress.getProgressDrawable();
layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress).setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(progressColor[counter], android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```